# Resize & text/Label for Vega Lite Bar Chart

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, vega-lite, deneb

_Hi, I would like to adjust my chart with the following needs, and I don't know how to do it ?

- Auto adjust all the chart when I resize it,
- Add the values on top of each bar,
- Add a text under each title with a specific information : ex %variation (and a variance
  indicator)
- Align charts like underlined

Thanks in advance for your help !

[image: My need]

```
   {
  "description": "Quatre graphiques identiques en grille.",
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "data_0",
      "values": [
        {"a": "1", "b": 28},
        {"a": "2", "b": 55},
        {"a": "3", "b": 43},
        {"a": "4", "b": 91},
        {"a": "5", "b": 81},
        {"a": "6", "b": 53},
        {"a": "7", "b": 19},
        {"a": "8", "b": 87},
        {"a": "9", "b": 52}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "data_1",
      "values": [
        {"a": "1", "b": 28},
        {"a": "2", "b": 55},
        {"a": "3", "b": 43},
        {"a": "4", "b": 91},
        {"a": "5", "b": 81},
        {"a": "6", "b": 53},
        {"a": "7", "b": 19},
        {"a": "8", "b": 87},
        {"a": "9", "b": 52}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "data_2",
      "values": [
        {"a": "1", "b": -3},
        {"a": "2", "b": -10},
        {"a": "3", "b": 43},
        {"a": "4", "b": 91},
        {"a": "5", "b": 81},
        {"a": "6", "b": 53},
        {"a": "7", "b": 19},
        {"a": "8", "b": -50},
        {"a": "9", "b": 52}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "data_3",
      "values": [
        {"a": "1", "b": -20},
        {"a": "2", "b": -5},
        {"a": "3", "b": -2},
        {"a": "4", "b": -20},
        {"a": "5", "b": -15},
        {"a": "6", "b": -30},
        {"a": "7", "b": -40},
        {"a": "8", "b": -35},
        {"a": "9", "b": -12}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "concat": [
    {
      "hconcat": [
        {
          "title": "Graphe 1.1",
          "mark": "bar",
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal"},
            "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"},
            "color": {"condition": {"test": "datum.b < 0", "value": "red"}, "value": "green"}
          }
        },
        {
          "title": "Graphe 1.2",
          "mark": "bar",
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal"},
            "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"},
            "color": {"condition": {"test": "datum.b < 0", "value": "red"}, "value": "green"}
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "hconcat": [
        {
          "title": "Graphe 2.1",
          "mark": "bar",
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal"},
            "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"},
            "color": {"condition": {"test": "datum.b < 0", "value": "red"}, "value": "green"}
          }
        },
        {
          "title": "Graphe 2.2",
          "mark": "bar",
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "a", "type": "nominal"},
            "y": {"field": "b", "type": "quantitative"},
            "color": {"condition": {"test": "datum.b < 0", "value": "red"}, "value": "green"}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is this for Power BI?

Comment: Also - that's a lot of questions. Please can you keep it to one question per post. If you let me know which one you'd like help with then I or someone else will try to help.

Comment: Hi David, yes, it is for powerbi. Let's start with the first one and i sugget i'd post 3 others questions ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, post each question separately. Unfortunately, the answer to your first question is that it is not currently possible to autosize concatenated charts (or other types of facet) like this in VegaLite. If you used Vega, then it could be done.

Comment: This is a long requested features with many issues on GitHub

Comment: is vega lite much easier than vega ?

Comment: Personally, I find Vega much easier than VL. VL is more terse to describe what you want to do but you lose some functionality. In Vega, you have to specify every detail but with that comes the power for edge cases like these.

Comment: VL transpiles to Vega under the covers. You can see the Vega code in the only editor at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Not sure to understand what screen you're talking about ?

Comment: I'll add it as answer so I can put a screenshot in.

Comment: I tried the posted translation of the code. But it won't work. Is it far from what it should be ? And then, what would be the code to resize all the chart as initialy Wondered ? Thanks

Comment: It should work the exact same if you ensure Vega is selected in Deneb instead of Vega Lite.

Comment: I've posted a screenshot of the Vega setting for you in Deneb.

Comment: Thanks very much. I started wth vega lite just because i thought it would be much easier or pratical. I 'll think twice then !

Comment: I've tried the online editor : wonderful. Thanks. Hence, I'll end this post and post other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, auto size doesn't currently work on VL concats or facets. To see the transpiled Vega, paste your code into the online editor and then either resize the section at the bottom or click the button highlighted in the screenshot below.

[image]

[image]